# How to force Xcode server connections over SSL

Tags: ios, ssl, continuous-integration, osx-mavericks, osx-server

The Issue:
Connecting to the Xcode server CI web interface over SSL with a provisioned iPad and attempting to download an integrated build fails with a message that it cannot connect.

The Setup:
I've just set up Mac OS X Server 3.01 on my home iMac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) for continuous integration. In the server admin panel only Xcode and File Sharing services are turned on. I've got continuous integration working from my MacBook Pro dev machine, configuring and running integration bots from the web UI served by the Xcode server on the iMac.

I want team members to have access to the CI web interface so I'm serving from the iMac to a public dynDNS address, port-mapped through from the Airport Extreme router to the iMac. This all works, but I want to force connecting only over SSL.

I did originally enable the Websites service in the server admin and created a redirect rule, configured with Source: "/", Destination: "https://myServer.dynDNSName.org", Status: "Permanent (301)". This did work to force all requests to port 443 and logging in worked as expected. When logging in to the CI interface with iPad Safari over SSL it is possible to navigate to the various bots results pages as expected. The problem is, tapping a built product link to download onto the provisioned iPad fails with the message, "Cannot connect to myServer.dynDNSName.org".

I have since turned off the server Websites service which once again allows connection over port 80. I don't want to allow clear text logins over port 80 because login accounts are server user accounts. My current workaround is to log in over SSL, then change the URL on the iPad to http://myServer.dynDNSName.org, to download the product, which then does install on the device.

So the question is, how can I set up the iMac server to not allow insecure logins and still enable downloading integrated products to devices?